# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in a multiple condition where statement

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to add an additional WHERE condition with AND to my mySQL query but keep getting the error **The multi-part identifier userR.externalSource could not be bound**
I have the alias setup in my left join from my other table but still I get this error. Could someone explain me why this is happening. I found [article](https://database.guide/sql-server-error-4104-the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound/) but this does not seem to be the case. I think it's rather a formatting issue of my query.

This query just counts 2 different groups of users but they can't have an empty (NULL) field for the externalSource field from the dbo.AAA_users table.

```
SELECT SUM(A.ROLECOUNT) AS 'Advanced Users' , 
    (SELECT SUM(A.ROLECOUNT)
    FROM (
        SELECT role.logicalName AS Role_name , 
                COUNT(DISTINCT users.userId) AS RoleCount  
        FROM dbo.AAA_UserRoleResource AS users
            LEFT JOIN dbo.AAA_Role AS role ON role.roleId = users.roleId
            LEFT JOIN dbo.AAA_User AS userR ON userR.userId = users.userId
        GROUP BY role.logicalName
        ) A
    WHERE A.Role_name IN ('ROLE_VIEWER', 'ROLE_USER') 
    AND userR.externalSource is not NULL <-- issue here  
    ) AS 'Basic user'
FROM(
    SELECT role.logicalName AS Role_name , 
            COUNT(DISTINCT users.userId) AS RoleCount 
    FROM dbo.AAA_UserRoleResource AS users
        LEFT JOIN dbo.AAA_Role AS role ON role.roleId = users.roleId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.AAA_User AS userR ON userR.userId = users.userId
    GROUP BY role.logicalName
    ) A 
WHERE A.Role_name IN ('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out why it was not working.

I was adding the additional WHERE condition outside of the parenthesis and because of this it did not find the identifier which is within the parenthesis.